# Angular 6 not a function exception

Tags: angular

I'm in the process of learning angular 6 and getting an exception. The exception is: "ERROR TypeError: this._lineGraphService.BuildLineGraph is not a function". Here are some of the files. Thanks in advance!

line-graph.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { GoogleLineGraphService } from '../google-line-graph.service';
import { LineGraphConfig } from '../models/LineGraphConfig';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-line-graph',
  templateUrl: './line-graph.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./line-graph.component.css']
})
export class LineGraphComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() dataFilePath: string;
  @Input() config: LineGraphConfig;
  @Input() elementId: string;

  constructor(private _lineGraphService: GoogleLineGraphService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._lineGraphService.BuildLineGraph(this.elementId, this.config);
  }
}
```

google-line-graph.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleChartsBaseService } from './google-charts-base.service'
import { LineGraphConfig } from './models/LineGraphConfig'

declare var google: any;
declare var $: any;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GoogleLineGraphService extends GoogleChartsBaseService {

  constructor() { super(); }

  BuildLineGraph(elementId: string, config: LineGraphConfig): void {

    var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(config.DataFilePath, { onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar });
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

    var chartFunc = () => { return new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(elementId)); };

    var options = {
      title: config.Title,
      width: 1550,
      height: 450,
      interpolateNulls: true,
      curveType: 'function',
      vAxis: {
        viewWindow: {
          min: 0
        },
        minValue: 0,
        title: config.XAxis
      },
      hAxis: {
        format: 'MMM dd',
        slantedText: true
      }
    };

    this.buildChart(data, chartFunc, options);
  }
}
```

Comment: Strange, I can;t reproduce. Can you please add `console.log('typeof this._lineGraphService.BuildLineGraph')` just above where the error is thrown, and let us know what it logs?

Comment: It logged it as undefined.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. Can you please provide an [mcve]?

Comment: Here you go: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/Ngvu7zuY2Su8uYKA?preview

Comment: It seems the issue has to do with inheritance and injection.  If I take the @Injectable part off the base class the error goes away.